# How to pass nested command to Docker run?

Tags: bash, docker

In my CI build, I'd like to print a formatted string which is built from some nested commands by Docker like:

```sh
docker run -t --rm -v /mysrc:/src -w /src node:lts echo "My project uses `npm list aLibrary`"
```

On bash, the command `` echo "My project uses `npm list aLibrary`" `` just runs perfectly, but when passing to Docker, neither backtick`` ` ``nor `$()` can be interpolated.

Anyone could help?

I've thought about making a `.sh` file to mount into the docker container, but a file would need a place to be stored, I think this simple CI script shouldn't be in a file.

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus if you read my post carefully, you'll find out that there would be no `Dockerfile` to be added !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
bash -c 'echo "My project uses `npm list aLibrary`"'
```

Answer (score 2):

this will work :

```
echo "My project uses `/usr/local/bin/npm list aLibrary`"
```

you need to supply the full path